# Bitmap to file android 6.0

Tags: android, file, bitmap

I get image from url and save it in memory of device. I had this:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... iUrl) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://lookw.ru/1/73/1380310809-pitstsa-ch1--16.jpg");
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "scetchpad";
                    File dir = new File(filepath);
                    File file = new File(dir, "pizza.png");
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fileOutputStream);
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
Log.d("LOGI", filepath);


                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                ImageView imageView =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                assert imageView != null;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }.execute();
```

**permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This code work on my tablet(android 4.1), but when I test it on my mobile phone(Xiaomi Mi Max android 6.0) i have some problem.

```
11-25 18:39:56.260 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/scetchpad/pizza.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-25 18:39:56.260 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
11-25 18:39:56.260 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
11-25 18:39:56.260 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
11-25 18:39:56.260 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.vkramarenko.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:47)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.vkramarenko.myapplication.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:38)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-25 18:39:56.261 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-25 18:39:56.262 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
11-25 18:39:56.262 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
11-25 18:39:56.262 19383-19480/com.vkramarenko.myapplication W/System.err:  ... 10 more
```

And I also don't see this directory(/storage/emulated/0) in memory of device, but some file(icon of app) save on this directory.

Comment: please log `filepath` after initializing it

Comment: `don't see this directory(/storage/emulated/0) in memory of device`. How are you trying to 'see'? Its a pretty normal path. It will be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at run time on `Android 6.0` devices. Check here for more info : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1):

In Android 6.0 It requieres Run time permission to store or read files. You can take look of following documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

If you don't want to handle this permission externally, You can avoid this by changing targetSdkVersion (in build.gradle) file to 22 or less than that.

defaultConfig {
        -----
        targetSdkVersion 22
        ------
    }